# How to load JSON Schema file from java

Tags: java, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

My Project is a maven project and inside resources folder - src/main/resources folder I have a json schema file - "jsonschema.json "

**package** : src/main/resources 
**file**    : jsonschema.json

Now i want to validate my jsonobject with json schema

How to load the schema.json file in to the code :

Is the below line correct?

```
JsonNode schema = JsonLoader.fromResource("/jsonschema.json");  // correct? or correct me
JsonNode data = JsonLoader.fromString(jsonData);
ProcessingReport report = validator.validate(schema, data);
```

Comment: file name : jsonschema.json  you are using schema.json? it is correct?

Comment: edited the question..it's a typo mistake

Comment: As the resource resides in the same folder as your calling class, just using `JsonLoader.fromResource("jsonschema.json")` should work for you.

Comment: @face: it was not in the same folder.. jsonschema is in src\main\resources folder and calling class in src\main\java\util package.so i was asking how to read that..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you 
Place jsonschema file on project root directory or in resource and read schema using normal file read and store it in variable say `str`

```
     booleab isValidRequest=false;
     String     requestData; // data to validate
     String str; //schema 

            JsonNode requestDataJsonNode = com.github.fge.jackson.JsonLoader.fromString(requestData);       
            final JsonNode schemaNode = JsonLoader.fromString(str);
           final JsonNode schemaNode=JsonLoader.fromResource("/jsonschema.json"); // for your query
            final JsonSchemaFactory factory = JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault();
            JsonValidator validator = factory.getValidator();        
            ProcessingReport processingReport=  validator.validate(schemaNode, requestDataJsonNode); 
            if(processingReport!=null)
            {
                isValidRequest=processingReport.isSuccess();
            }
            
            } catch (Exception e) {
                
            }
```

If You are getting exception while executing the program.
add  dependencies listed in below [link]

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.fge/json-schema-validator/2.2.5

Comment: even it's a normal file i need to pass the path..right? so what should i pass it for the file available under src\main\resources. can u add that part...!

Comment: Try this YourClassName.class.getClass().getResource("/jsonschema.json");

Comment: Note that the library specifies a `resource` scheme which you can use to load resources from the classpath; so you can load from URI `resource:/wherever/your/json/is`

Comment: @fge : The code used by me was in answer section..! <dependency>
   <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
   <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId> 
   <version>2.2.5</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: I want to eliminate the unnecessary dependencies or exclude the dependencies from <groupid>com.github.fge </group-id>. from the above code snippet, what else can be unnecessary for me .. i found several jars like javax.mail , google code etc from "mvn dependency-tree"

Comment: INFO] +- com.github.fge:json-schema-validator:jar:2.2.5:compile 
[INFO] |  +- com.github.fge:json-schema-core:jar:1.2.4:compile 
[INFO] |  |  +- com.github.fge:uri-template:jar:0.9:compile 
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.github.fge:msg-simple:jar:1.1:compile  
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com.github.fge:btf:jar:1.2:compile

Comment: [INFO] |  |  |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:16.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.github.fge:jackson-coreutils:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.mozilla:rhino:jar:1.7R4:compile
[INFO] |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:jar:6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.mail:mailapi:jar:1.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:jar:4.6:compile
Do we need all those dependencies..